# My java program only outputs 4's and i don't knwo why

Tags: java

This code only outputs 4's and I don't know why.
Is it maybe because of the static main or why? thanks

```
class Calculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 3;
    boolean op = false;
    int pi = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < 99999999; i++) {
        if(op == false) {
            pi = pi - 1 / x;
            op = true;
            x = x+2;
            System.out.println(pi*4);
        } else if(op == true) {
            pi = pi + 1 / x;
            op = false;
            x = x+2;
            System.out.println(pi*4);
        }
        
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `1 / x` is always `0` because this is an int division, and `x` is always greater than 1.

Answer (score 0):

As `1` is of type `int`, and `x` also has the type `int`, `1/x` will also be an `int`. Now, because `x>3>2` for the whole program, `1/x` is always equal to `0`. Therefore, `pi` will always be `1`.

To fix this error, I would suggest changing `pi` to a `double`  and calculation the inverse of `x` with `1d/x`.

Answer (score 0):

Below line of code always return constant value as you are trying to do **`1/x`** , it's always gives you 0.33,0.11...

And rounding of it will give you 0.

That's why from pi=pi-0, always return constant value.

```
        pi = pi - 1 / x;
        op = true;
        x = x+2;
```